# Install package to a custom path with composer doesn't working

Tags: php, yii, composer-php

I used this [link](http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md), but for me doesn't working...

```
{
"name": "vendor/work-team-betting",
"description": "Team betting webapplication for an event.",
"type": "webapplication",
"authors": [
    {

    }
],
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "application/vendor"
},
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "application/framework/{$name}": ["yiisoft/yii"]
    }
},
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "~1.0",
    "yiisoft/yii": "1.1.14"         
}
}
```

I use this composer.json, but after installation the composer didn't move the yiisoft/yii into my application/framework/ directory.
Anybody can help me, what did I do wrong? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible, because Yii does (and [will](https://github.com/composer/installers/pull/71)) not use custom [composer installers](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md), which would be required to make this work.

To quote from the composer installers README:

> The following frameworks natively work with Composer and will be installed to the default vendor directory. composer/installers is not needed to install packages with these frameworks: [...] Yii

https://github.com/composer/installers

This also applies to the framework package itself and I'd strongly recommend you **not** to change this behavior.

If you need to work around some glitches, these articles may be helpful to you:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/392/creating-yii-applications-with-composer
- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/457/fixing-extensions-without-modifying-their-code

Answer (score 0):

In general [schmunk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291573/schmunk) is totaly right. But one workaround could be to fork the original Yii repository and build up your own one, where you only change everything to use it with composer installer.

Basically you need to define a own type or misuse an existing one.

I found a good tutorial on how to extend composer installer by own types here:

http://clearcode.cc/2014/10/composer-installer-plugin-usage/

And I have written an article about how I used the composer installer package to get my packages installed to a custom folder:

http://www.ask-sheldon.com/custom-install-path-composer/

The important point is, that I misused another repository type to get it work the way I wanted it. 
Perhaps these information help you to do the same with a fork of the Yii-package.

Comment: BTW: Now it is supported by installer composer! :-D
Why did I get alerts for such old stuff? #negromancer

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me.
The custom modules and themes were all being installed in vendor directory. installed-paths.

I needed to also do the following.

Add your custom types to the `"installer-types"`:

`"installer-types": ["library","my-type-1","my-type-2"]`

https://packagist.org/packages/oomphinc/composer-installers-extender

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my CMS EFFCORE...

File *composer.json*:

```
"name": "project_n",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.9",
    "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^2.0"
},
"config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
        "composer/installers": true,
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": true
    }
}
"extra": {
    "installer-types": [
        "MY_TYPE-module"
    ],
    "installer-paths": {
        "modules/{$name}": [
            "type:MY_TYPE-module"
        ]
    }
}
```

File *composer.json* in module:

```
"name": "project_n/module_m",
"type": "MYTYPE-module",
```